How to Ensure Blacklisted Headers Are Not Logged in Report Portal with RestAssured?
I'm using RestAssured for API testing, and I've implemented a logging filter to integrate with Report Portal and Allure. I've configured it to blacklist sensitive headers like x-key to prevent them from being logged. However, I'm still seeing this header in the logs on Report Portal.
Here’s a snippet of my code:
public static RequestSpecification prepareRequest() {
    return given()
            .filters(
                    new ReportPortalRestAssuredLoggingFilter(42, LogLevel.INFO,
                            SanitizingHttpHeaderConverter.INSTANCE,
                            DefaultHttpHeaderConverter.INSTANCE)
                            .setBodyTypeMap(BODY_TYPE_MAP),
                    new AllureRestAssured())
            .config(RestAssuredConfig.config().logConfig(LogConfig.logConfig().blacklistHeader("x-key")));
}

// Example API call
response = prepareRequest()
            .config(setConnectionTimeout())
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .headers("x-key", myKey())
            .body(requestPayload.toString())
            .post(baseURL)
            .andReturn();

Issue:
Despite blacklisting the x-key header, it still appears in the logs on Report Portal. I expected that the header would be excluded from the logged output due to the blacklist configuration.
Questions:
Is the blacklist functionality in RestAssured correctly implemented for use with Report Portal?
How can I ensure that sensitive headers do not appear in the Report Portal logs?
Are there alternative approaches to securely handle and log sensitive headers while using RestAssured and Report Portal?

The config setting the blacklistHeader seems to be overwritten with the config setting the connection timeout.
